Unable to update Task record
Error details in production -
Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id XXXXXXXX_ID_XXXXXX; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on object id: []
Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Txxxxxxxxxxxx; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on object id: []
caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Txxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on object id: []
Class.DaScoopComposer line 620, column 1
Class.DaScoopComposer line 399, column 1
Class.DaScoopComposer line 35, column 1
I am unable to access the code in DaScoopComposer as it is a managed package. However, when I attempt to replicate the issue in UAT, I encounter the following error message screen.
Issue: User2, who is positioned lower in the role hierarchy, is attempting to update a task record owned by User1, who is higher in the hierarchy in same level.
OWD in PROD:
Account, contact, Opportunity - Private
Activity - Private
Profile level  ---> System permissions ---> Has edit access on Task
Any suggestions or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You need to open a case with the package vendor.
